# Delegate that can run internal code only every X seconds

Tags: c#, loops, timer

I am trying to make a method which will returns a delegate that can be invoked every millisecond but I want to restrict it to run slow operation not every time when it is invoked but let say minimum once in 5 seconds.

Tried to achieve that with Timer and Stopwatch but couldn't stick to affordable solution.

**1st approach:**

```
public Func<bool> GetCancelRequestedFunc(string _taskName)
{
    var checkStatus = false;
    var timer = new Timer(5000);
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => { checkStatus = true; };

    return () =>
    {
        if (checkStatus)
        {
            bool result;
            checkStatus = false;

            //long operation here

            return result;
        }

        return false;
    };
}
```

1st approach seems better to me however it is not working - long operation here never invoked and I can't find out why. May be need pass `checkStatus` as `ref` but not sure how to make it in that case

**2nd approach:**

```
public Func<bool> GetCancelRequestedFunc(string _taskName)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    return () =>
    {
        var mod = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 5000;     
        if (mod > 0 && mod < 1000)
        {
            bool result;

            //long operation here

            return result;
        }

        return false;
    };
}
```

This one works... But very unreliable because it seems that check performed during 6th second if delegate invoked. However it will be invoked all the time during 6th second.

Can you say what is wrong with 1st approach or may be suggest better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need any timer here, just remember the time when you last executed your function:

```
public Func<bool> GetCancelRequestedFunc(string taskName)
{
    DateTime lastExecution = DateTime.Now;

    return () =>
    {
        if(lastExecution.AddMinutes(5)<DateTime.Now) 
        {
            lastExecution = DateTime.Now;
            bool result;

            //long operation here

            return result;
        }

        return false;
    };
}
```